# Accessing properties from an extended class

Tags: java

I'm trying to crate a Model structure, to access a database, inspired by Laravel's Eloquent (PHP).

Basically I've got a class called `Model`, and for now it's just empty.

I then got another class called `User`, which extends `Model`

```
public class User extends Model {

    private String table = "users";
}
```

As you can see the User class also got a property called table, which refers to the table on the database the model is representing.

Inside of my `Model.java` I'm then trying to fetch the name of the table.

So far I'm running some code on my `Model.java` constructor where I go through all of the fields, on the instance. This gives me a Field object, but I'm unable to get the content of table from `Model.java`

`Model.java` :

```
public abstract class Model {

    public Model()
    {
        List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Class<?> c = this.getClass(); c != null; c = c.getSuperclass()) {
            fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(c.getDeclaredFields()));
        }
        for (Field field : fields)
        {
            String name = field.getName(); //returns "table"
        }
    }
}
```

All In all, what I need to is to get the table name from the class that's extends model.

Any ideas? or is this a bad practice?

Comment: Model should have an abstract method, getTableName. It is bad practice, a class should never know details about classes that inherit it

Comment: Would you care to enlighten me on how you would do that? :) I haven't really worked with abstract methods before.

Comment: You will override it with a concrete method in your extended class, creating a simple getter for your private variable.

Comment: But this will mean that I will have to create that method for every class that extends Model, right?

Comment: Why don't you let the subclasses utilize annotation that you define? By default, the name of the class (or plural thereof) is the name of the table.

Comment: @KedarMhaswade I would do that, but you can always count on that :). I would like the option to be explicit about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model should have an abstract method, `getTableName`

Yes it is bad practice because a class should not know details about class that inherit from it.

The way you are doing it, there's no contract that specifies that a subclass must implement that field.

By creating a method that has to be implemented by subclass, there's a clear contract and you are applying the dependency inversion principle. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle

```
public abstract class Model {

    public Model() {}

    abstract String getTableName();
}

public class User extends Model() {
    public String getTableName(){
      return "users";
    }
}
```

Comment: I really get what you're saying, but I might as well just create an interface then. In this way, I would have to implement the same method in each class, that basically does the same.

Comment: Does the same? Wouldn't they all return a different table name?

Comment: Ahh, I see where you're going with this. The edit made it clear, thank you :)